# Laravel asynchronous workers

Tags: php, laravel, message-queue, worker

I'm trying to setup Laravel 5.7 queues to run at literally the same time. Async. I'm getting a lot of answers through Google/Stack Overflow, however they all just say "set the driver to database". That doesn't work. We have the database driver set up, and a worker running as a daemon. Just the one worker.

As people use the app, it may need to process some data using a third party API which can take time, while this is processing other people are doing other things that require other jobs. Right now, it's all happening sequentially. Job A has to finish before Job B runs.

I would like Job A, and B to run at exactly the same time. Or, I want Job B to start/end even though Job A is already running.

**How does laravel support this? Do I need to create many workers, and have each category of jobs run under a different worker?**

`nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Thanks

Comment: create different worker which have different queue. ex: worker1 run `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --queue=channel1` and worker2 run `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --queue=channel2`

Comment: Okay its as simple as that. Perfect. Over thinking as usual. I suspected it might be more complex and Laravel would have a "way" to do it.

Comment: In Laravel Forge, we can set processes to a >1 number

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Supervisor Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration) of the Queues documentation.

> In this example, the `numprocs` directive will instruct Supervisor to run 8 `queue:work` processes and monitor all of them, automatically restarting them if they fail.

If you aren't running supervisor you can spawn up more `php artisan queue:work` processes on your own, but Supervisor monitors that stuff for you.

Comment: Laravel Forge takes care of this with the processes field.

Comment: That's assuming OP is using Forge.

Comment: Yes, just wanted  to put the information out here in case someone stumbles upon it..

Comment: Yea I tried to get my lead to install supervisord on the server but he insisted in writing his own script which does `$(pgrep -f 'php artisan queue:work' | wc -w)` to check and executes the bash script in a Laravel cron job.

Comment: My best advice is to show the lead why supervisor is better than a very naive bash script that limits you to updating the script every time you want to add/remove workers. At least if it's stored in a supervisor config you can track it in the repo.